# jQuery Flot Charts + Overwrite xAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each, flot

I get the data via an AJAX request and it looks like this:

```
[1,3252325],[2,2323]
```

The second value is the file id called `fId`

Now I try to get that id and make another ajax call to find out the corresponding name and use it to override the x-axis description.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that everytime it runs, it deletes all existing names. Therefor, at the end, I am left with only one, the last, dataset that has a custom xAxis description.

What I need is that in the end all datasets have their custom new name for the xAxis.

I tried to search the API.txt but couldnt find anything about it. I did also try for hours to move the code around or rewrite it, but after all I am stuck with the same problem.

Thats the part of the code:

```
function onDataReceived(series) {

    //Add data
    if (!alreadyFetched[series.label]) {
        alreadyFetched[series.label] = true;
        fdata.push(series);

        //Get ID
        var fId = [series.data[0][0]];

        //Get names
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/admin.inc.php?action=get&option=filename&id='+fId+'',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response){
                $.plot(fplaceholder, fdata,$.extend(true, {}, foptions, {

                    //Works, but each time it runs, it removes all previous overrides
                    xaxis:{ticks:[[fId,response]]}

                }));
            }
        });
    }

}

$.ajax({
    url: dataurl,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: onDataReceived
});
```

UPDATE:

I am currently using a "hack" to make this work how I want it, but this is probably only working for my specific needs:

I set the xaxis "show decimal numbers" to false. After the plot is built, I start a timeout function to search all xaxis values (ids in my case) and find the corresponding name with a small ajax call.

I am still looking how to do it directly within the flot code though.

Comment: This isn't really related to Flot; you just need to restructure your requests to first build up a list of xaxis values, then create the plot.

Comment: I tried to move the ajax part around, but I am just not able to get it to work, therefor I hope some1 here can help. I can change the title if neccessary.